# View Dataframe in R - Error in View : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple code written as follows

```
df <- data.frame(iris)
```

When I click on this data frame to view the df (in RStudio), it throws me this error

```
> View(df)
Error in View : attempt to apply non-function
```

Any idea whats happening here? I am using `Oracle R 3.1.1` (not MS R)

Comment: I do not know why this is happening. However, I came across this question because the same thing happens to me using RStudio with standard R version 3.3.2 (and now version 3.3.3). Seeing you were using an Oracle version of R, I figured it may have to do with the  Oracle OREbase package I have loaded. When I detached that package, the error goes away and RStudio's view works fine. Perhaps you could add _roracle_ and _rstudio_ tags to your question?